# Getting The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. error while uploading file to share point document library using SSIS

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ssis

I want to upload a file from local directory to Share Point document library using SSIS. I am using Script Task to do so. While running the package I am getting below error:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Script Task code is as below:

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            WebClient myWebClient;
            string DestinationURL;
            string LocalFileName;
            bool FireAgain = true;
            try
            {
                myWebClient = new WebClient();
                myWebClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a test!");
                LocalFileName = @"C:\Users\jay.desai\Desktop\LSRSQL01_ACXM_20201003.html";
                DestinationURL = @"https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/DataServices/Shared%20Documents/Data%20Dictionaries/LSRSQL01_ACXM_20201003.html";
                Console.WriteLine(LocalFileName);
                myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("jay.desai@companyname.com", "HelloWorld@2891", "NATSYS");
                myWebClient.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                //myWebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, String.Empty, String.Format("Uploading {0} to {1}", LocalFileName, DestinationURL), String.Empty, 0, ref FireAgain);
                // upload the file
                myWebClient.UploadFile(DestinationURL, "PUT", LocalFileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Catch and handle error
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, String.Empty, ex.Message, String.Empty, 0);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

I am able to open the same folder and upload the file using browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got resolved by using CSOM. For that first you need to install SharePoint Online Client Components SDK. Then in the project you have to reference `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime`. Microsoft reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee956524(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#uploading-documents-to-document-libraries)

Use below code in script task:

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://companyname.sharepoint.com");

            SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "HelloWorld@1234".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("jay.desai@company.com", passWord);

            using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\jay.desai\Desktop\LSRSQL01_ACXM_20201003.html", FileMode.Open))
            ClientOM.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, "/sites/DataServices/Shared Documents/Data Dictionaries/LSRSQL01_ACXM_20201003.html", fileStream, true);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
         }
```

Comment: do you have to install this SDK on SSIS server too ? to make this work ? thx

Comment: Yes we have to install this SDK on server too. Enjoy